# How can we use service locator in custom flutter library or package?

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, package, service-locator

I want to split my app into features and each feature in a package, so how can we apply dependency injection using [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) in each package individually

"each package represent a feature containing all business logic and ui for that feature"

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `Interface` as a contract for the methods you are going to use from this package.

Then, implement this interface in a new class and wrap the package inside this class with the implementation of the package.

Finally, use your service locator with this class in the same way that you always doing with your normal classes.

Ex.

```dart
abstract class Encryptor{

  Future<String> encrypt(String input);
  Future<String> decrypt(String input);
}


class EncryptorImpl implement Encryptor{

  Future<String> encrypt(String input){
    final result = await encrypt.encrypt("myKey", input);
    return result;
 }
  Future<String> decrypt(String input){
//same!!
.
.
  }
}
```

Comment: please,  can you read the question again  i made some changes to clarify it.